# Shiny Modal not showing as intended in server

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog

So I am currently writing a test Shiny app game to test my helper functions I am writing for the main game app.

In the main app, the withdrawal amount and some other parameters will be provided by the player or will be initialised during the game, so I am using test values of 1860 for the `withdrawals` and 1400 for the `vals$cashbalance` for now.

The main point of this test Shiny app is to test if players will be able to liquidate loans correctly. If the `vals$cashbalance` plus 70% of the `loanValue` of all the loans in the `loanData` is still less than the withdrawal amount, then there should be a `selectLoansLiquidateModal` popping up allowing player to select how many of each type of loans to convert their `loanValue` (one of the attributes in the `loanData` dataframe) into cash and be removed from their `loanData` dataframe.

However, one problem I am facing is that even though the 1860 for the `withdrawals` and 1400 for the `vals$cashbalance` should cause the `selectLoansLiquidateModal` to pop up, it does not. I have already tested the LiquidateLoans() function by itself and it works as intended.

```
# import database data
source("usePackages.R")
loadPkgs(c("sqldf","shiny","shinyalert","dplyr"))

#### Helper Function Section
selectLoansLiquidateModal <- function(loan.type.1.min=0, loan.type.1.max=2, 
                                      loan.type.2.min=0, loan.type.2.max=2, 
                                      loan.type.3.min=0, loan.type.3.max=2){
  modalDialog(
    title = "Select loans to liquidate.",
    numericInput("loantype1", "Select number of $200 Loans to liquidate", value = 0, 
                 min = loan.type.1.min, max = loan.type.1.max),
    numericInput("loantype2", "Select number of $300 Loans to liquidate", value = 0, 
                 min = loan.type.2.min, max = loan.type.2.max),
    numericInput("loantype3", "Select number of $600 Loans to liquidate", value = 0,
                 min = loan.type.3.min, max = loan.type.3.max),
    
    footer = tagList(
      actionButton("loanliquidatesubmission", "Confirm loans to liquidate")
    )
    
  )
}

updateCashBalance <- function(cashbalance, newamt){
  newcashbal <- cashbalance + newamt
  return(newcashbal)
}

SelectLoans <- function(numberofeachtypeofloan,eachtypeofloan){
  loansselected <- data.frame(loan.type = eachtypeofloan, no.of.each.type.of.loan = numberofeachtypeofloan)
  #need both arguments to be numerical vectors
  return(loansselected)
}

LiquidateLoans <- function(cashbalance=1400, withdrawalamount=1860, 
                           loanData=data.frame(loanID = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
                                               loanType=c(1,2,3,2,2), 
                                               loanValue = c(200, 300, 600, 300, 300), 
                                               durationToMaturity = c(3,1,2,2,3)), 
                           loansselected=SelectLoans(c(1,2,0),c(1,2,3)), percentage=0.7){
  
  # Keep track of loanValue of liquidated loans
  removed_loans_value = 0
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(loansselected)){
    loan_type <- loansselected$loan.type[i]
    num_rows_to_remove <- loansselected$no.of.each.type.of.loan[i]
    
    # Filter the rows in loanData with loanValue equal to loan_type
    filtered_rows <- loanData[loanData$loanType == loan_type, ]
    
    if (num_rows_to_remove != 0 & nrow(filtered_rows) >= num_rows_to_remove) {
      # Sort the filtered rows by durationToMaturity in descending order
      sorted_rows <- filtered_rows[order(filtered_rows$durationToMaturity, decreasing = TRUE), ]
      
      # Find the rows to remove
      rows_to_remove <- sorted_rows[1:num_rows_to_remove, ]
      print(rows_to_remove) #for debugging
      
      # Calculate the loanValue of the loans that will be removed
      removed_loans_value <- sum(rows_to_remove$loanValue) + removed_loans_value
      print(removed_loans_value) #for debugging
      
      # Remove the top num_rows_to_remove rows from loanData
      loanData <- loanData[!(loanData$loanID %in% rows_to_remove$loanID), ]
    }
    
    if(nrow(filtered_rows) < num_rows_to_remove){
      stop(sprintf("You liquidated more loans of type %s than what you own",i))
    }
  }
  
  # Update cash balance after liquidating loans and satisfying withdrawals
  cashbalance <- updateCashBalance(cashbalance, percentage*removed_loans_value-withdrawalamount)
  result_list <- list(resultloanData = loanData, resultcashbalance = cashbalance, removed_loans_value = removed_loans_value)
  return(result_list)
}

getMaxLoan <- function(loanData){
  loan_type_counts <- loanData %>%group_by(loanType) %>% tally()
  result_list <- list(one = loan_type_counts[1,2], two = loan_type_counts[2,2], three = loan_type_counts[3,2])
  return(result_list)
}



# updateCashInventory(month=3, deposits=3000, withdrawals=withdrawalamount, loanPayout=0,cashOnHand=cashbalance)      
# need to update loan inventory too

# test function
test <- function(){
  # test liquidate loans
  loanData <- data.frame(loanID = c(1,2,3,4,5), loanType=c(1,2,3,2,2), loanValue = c(200, 300, 600, 300, 300), durationToMaturity = c(3,1,2,2,3)) #for testing
  numberofeachtypeofloan <- c(1,2,0) #for testing
  eachtypeofloan <- c(1,2,3) #for testing
  loansselected <- SelectLoans(numberofeachtypeofloan,eachtypeofloan)
  print(loansselected)
  result_list <- LiquidateLoans(cashbalance=1400, withdrawalamount=1860, loanData, loansselected, percentage=0.7)
  return(result_list)
}

#### UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("nextmonth", "Next Month")
)


#### Server Section
#the following will be in the server function after some observe event of a customer withdrawing:
server <- function(input, output, session){
  vals <- reactiveValues(cashbalance = 1400, 
                         loanData = data.frame(loanID = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
                                               loanType=c(1,2,3,2,2), 
                                               loanValue = c(200, 300, 600, 300, 300), 
                                               durationToMaturity = c(3,1,2,2,3)),
                         numberofeachtypeofloan=c(0,0,0),
                         eachtypeofloan=c(0,0,0),
                         percentage=0.7)

  observeEvent(input$nextmonth, {
    print("This is the current cash balance:")
    print(vals$cashbalance)
    print("This is the current loan data:")
    print(vals$loanData)
    
    withdrawals <- 1860 #as test
    #Note: when testing below chunk outside of app, comment out all the showModals and shinyAlerts.
    if(withdrawals <= vals$cashbalance){
      vals$cashbalance <- updateCashBalance(vals$cashbalance, -1*withdrawals)
      print("No liquidation needed")
    }else{
      if(vals$percentage*sum(loanData$loanValue)+ vals$cashbalance < withdrawals){
        stop("Game has ended due to inability to meet withdrawal demand")
        
        #notification to tell player the game has ended
        shinyalert("You do not have enough loans to liquidate and cover the withdrawal. The game has ended.", type = "error")
      }else{
        print("im here")
        max_number_list <- getMaxLoan(vals$loanData)
        
        #window with drop-down selections on loans for players to select from to liquidate
        showModal(selectLoansLiquidateModal(loan.type.1.min=0, loan.type.1.max=max_number_list$one, 
                                            loan.type.2.min=0, loan.type.2.max=max_number_list$two, 
                                            loan.type.3.min=0, loan.type.3.max=max_number_list$three))
        
        
        loansselected <- SelectLoans(vals$numberofeachtypeofloan,vals$eachtypeofloan) #now assuming both are vectors of numbers
        print('loans selected:')
        print(loansselected) #for debugging
        
        result_list <- LiquidateLoans(vals$cashbalance, withdrawals, vals$loanData, loansselected, vals$percentage)
        #print(percentage*result_list$removed_loans_value)
        if(vals$percentage*result_list$removed_loans_value+vals$cashbalance < withdrawals){
          stop("Did not meet withdrawal demand, liquidate more loans")
          
          #notification to show the loans selected are not enough to cover the withdrawal
          shinyalert("You have not selected enough loans to cover the withdrawal. Please select more loans", type = "error")
        } else {
          print(result_list) #for debugging
          vals$loanData <- result_list$resultloanData
          vals$cashbalance <- result_list$resultcashbalance
        }
      }
    }
    
    print("This is the updated loan data:")
    print(vals$loanData)
    print("This is the updated cash balance:")
    print(vals$cashbalance)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$loanliquidatesubmission, {
    removeModal()
    vals$numberofeachtypeofloan <- c(input$loantype1, input$loantype2, input$loantype3)
    vals$eachtypeofloan <- c(1,2,3)
  })
  
}      

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It is difficult for people to help you because they cannot even run your code.  We can't do the `source("usePackages.R")`.  Moreover, your entire code has a lot of stuff unrelated to getting the modal to open.  Please try to make a minimal, reproducible sample of code.

Comment: My vague guess is that you're not entering the if/else block that opens the modal.  Perhaps relatedly, I don't see where `loanData$loanValue` comes from.